# Identifying a sequence of intervals that cover the entire real line while their widths get arbitrarily small

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been playing around with a lot of intervals and I'm trying to find a way to cover all of $\mathbb R$ with these intervals, while the width of the intervals get arbitrarily small.

I have been unable to find a way to do this and any advice, hints or examples would be greatly appreciated! I know how to do it if I'm only interested in $[-1,1]$, for example.

Comment: Use intervals of length $\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and take advantage of the fact that $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1n$ is divergent.

Comment: I agree. But how can I express this in a way that covers the entire real line?

Comment: Are you using closed intervals, or open intervals? The former is a little easier.

Comment: "I agree. But how can I express this in a way that covers the entire real line"  Then intervals are $[-1,1]$ and $[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac 1k]$ and  $-[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k, -\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac 1k]$

Answer (score 0):

Just take Brian Scott suggestion.

$A= \{[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1k]: n\in \mathbb N\}$ will cover $[1,\infty)$ with intervals being arbitrarily small. ($[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1k]$ will but of length $\frac 1{n+1}$.)

And $B = \{[-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1k, \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1k]: n\in \mathbb N\}$ will cover $(-\infty, 1]$ with intervals being arbitrarily small.

And so $A\cup B \cup \{[-1,1]\}$ will cover all $\mathbb R$.

If you need open intervals just nudge these a bit and allow over lap.

$A'= \{(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k, \sum_{k=1}^{n+2} \frac 1k): n\in \mathbb N\}$

$B'= \{(-\sum_{k=1}^{n+2} \frac 1k, -\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1k): n\in \mathbb N\}$

$A'\cup B' \cup \{(-1.1, 1.1)\}$